# SpringMVC url rewrite with tuckey UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: java, spring-mvc, url-rewriting, restful-url, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

How can I rewrite url in SpringMVC with [tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) like this:

From

`http://localhost:8080/demo/api.do?method=getUser&uid=1001`

to

`http://localhost:8080/demo/api/user/1001`

The controller snippets:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api.do")
public class APIController {

    @RequestMapping(params = "method=getUser")
    public String methodName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //CODE BLOCK
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a dependency if you're using maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Enable the filter in your *web.xml*

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add the following rule to *WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml*

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/demo/api.do?method=getUser&amp;uid=(.*)$</from>
       <to>/demo/api/user/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need use URL rewrite filer? Why not define two methods for both types of URL and route to single method to handle processing

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo/api.do?"....)
public void method1(){
  //...
  handler();
}
@RequestMapping(value = "/demo/api/user/{user-id}"....)
public void method1(){
  //...
  handler();
}

private void handler(){
    //This method will have all the controller logic
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SpringMVC, you can do it simply

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class APIController {

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public ModelAndView methodName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //CODE BLOCK

        // to redirect other view 
        new ModelAndView("...your view page");
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user/{user_id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public String methodName(HttpServletRequest request) {
        //CODE BLOCK
    }
}
```

`@ResponseBody` if you send only object values

also you can send `user_id` as param

```
public String methodName(@RequestParam("user_id") String userid, Model model)
```

Important thing you have add `Bean` for view resolver, here is annotation based example

```
@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver resolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");        
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");    // what you used 
    resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    return resolver;
}
```