# UrlRewrite in Tuckey over https not working

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, https, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I'm trying to use the [tuckey's UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) over https channel like this

From

https://localhost:8443/daruma/Employer/EditProfile?action=post

to

https://localhost:8443/daruma/Employer/EditProfile/action/post

I'm ware that this question probably duplicate with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392785/springmvc-url-rewrite-with-tuckey-urlrewritefilter), but something is off, I have followed the instruction by setting up my configuration as follow

web.xml

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>confPath</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

pom.xml

```
    <!-- URL Rewriting -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
        <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
```

WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

```
<urlrewrite>
  <rule match-type="regex">
    <from>^/daruma/Employer/EditProfile?action=([a-z]+)$</from>
    <to>/daruma/Employer/EditProfile/action/$1</to>
  </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

And my method in controller is simple like this

```
  @RequestMapping(value = { "Employer/EditProfile",
          "employer/editcompany" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String editView(Locale locale, HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request,
          Model model) {

          //something that seem to be right

  }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `daruma` the [context root](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html#bnaeb) for the application?  If yes, either remove `/daruma` from the URLs or use `<urlrewrite use-context="true">`.  It is generally preferable not to use the context root in configuration files as it limits your deployment options (to a single context root).  It will be better to code your URLs without the context root.

Comment: Yes, I did remove it and add the use-context="true" in urlrewrite as you suggest but it's still not working.

Comment: You don't need to do the two things together.  Only one of them is required.  Post a sample app on Github that someone can try.