# How to rewrite this url in spring mvc in java

Tags: java

from= Demo/user.Search_Candidate.form?action=clickOnCandidate&userId=25

to=  Demo/click_candidate

Comment: Via typing. Am I missing something?

Comment: Please add a correct description of what you want to achieve and the code that you've already tried solving the problem with. If it's unclear, please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Enable the filter in your web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

Add the following rule to WEB-INF/urlrewrite.xml

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
       <from>^/demo/api.do?method=getUser&amp;uid=(.*)$</from>
       <to>/demo/api/user/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

You can use any **tuckey UrlRewriteFilter**

For that :

> **Add a dependency if you're using maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.tuckey</groupId>
    <artifactId>urlrewritefilter</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392785/springmvc-url-rewrite-with-tuckey-urlrewritefilter) can help u.

Comment: Or you could just change the `@RequestMapping` value